# Ajax отправка POST запроса на сервлет (Java)

Tags: java, ajax, servlet

Проблема следующая. Есть сервлет на сервере, который принимает данные в формате json

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public class AuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;

            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line);

                String query=sb.toString();

        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }//

    }
```

Когда тестирую свой сервлет прогой Advanced REST client - посылаю пост запрос со строкой в виде json, то все работает нормально. Но если отправляю запрос через ajax, товсе летит к чертям. Как я выяснил, на каком-то этапе в строку добавляются экранирующие символы "\" т.к. в строке много кавычек. Вот ajax код.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){

        query = $("#json").val();
        var userJson = JSON.stringify(dataa);
        //
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",//Метод передачи
            data: userJson,//Передаваемые данные в JSON - формате
            url: 'simple',//Название сервлета
            contentType: "application/json",
            error: function(message) {
                $("#response").html(message);
                console.log("request="+message.responseText);

            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data);
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
```

Похоже я что-то делаю не так. Как это исправить? И еще вопрос. Ответ от сервера я собираюсь вставлять в страницу через .innerHTML или .html. Не уверен, что это хорошая практика.

Comment: Что значит "все летит к чертям"?

Comment: Я же написал, что в случае отправки запроса через ajax, в строку запроса почему-то добавляются экранирующие символы(/). И такой запрос сервлет уже не обрабатывает, выдает ошибку.

Comment: Если ориентироваться на приведённый вами код, то ошибок не должно быть даже в том случае, если сервлету отправить арабскую вязь вперемешку с emoji. Добавьте к вопросу полный текст ошибки.